# Pop up email a friend window on site j query .dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Can some please help me with this. I created a button where a user can click on and it opens a new window which allows the person to fill out the forms on the page and share a property with a friend...

instead i want it to be a pop up dialog box which will  have the main page in the background .. here is my code can some one please help

```
$('.profileHeader').after('<div id="emailWrapper" class="right"/>');
$('#emailWrapper').prepend($('li.five'));
$('li.five').css({"width": 142,"height": 50});
$("li.five").addClass("nice medium orange radius button right headerEmailAFriend");
$(".five > .event-click").css({"border-style": "none"});
$(".five > .event-click").css({"color": "#ffffff"});
$('.#emailWrapper').click(function () {
    $("#emailWrapper").dialog("open");
    event.preventDefault();
    href = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(href);
    url.dialog({
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 140,
        modal: true,
    });
});
```

I CHANGED UP MY CODE THE BOTTOM PART I REALIZED I NEEDED TO REMOVE THE DOT... NEW ERROR IS THAT WHEN I CLICK THE BUTTON NOW THE BUTTON GOES AWAY HERE IS THE CODE

```
$('#emailWrapper').click(function() {
event.preventDefault();
$('#emailWrapper').dialog({
    resizable: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 140,
    modal: true,
});
```

OK THIS IS WHAT I HAVE NOW BASED ON WHAT I GOT FROM THIS FORM... STILL HAVE AN ERROR

```
< div id = "emailWrapper" > < p > emailWrapper < /p>
</div > $('#emailWrapper').dialog({
resizable: false,
autoOpen: false,
height: 140,
modal: tue
});
$("#emailWrapper").dialog("open");
```

---

```
$('#emailWrapper > li > a').bind('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var url = $(this).attr('href');
$('body').prepend('<div id="loadEmailFriend" class=""/>');
$('#loadEmailFriend').load(url, function () {
$('#loadEmailFriend').dialog({
     resizable: false,
     autoOpen: false,
     height: 140,
     modal: true,


     });
});

     $("#emailWrapper").dialog("open");
 });
```

Here is the new code i came up with.. problem now is that nothing comes up in a dialog box. I am trying to take the information that comes up on another page (email a friend) and make it into a dialog box which just pops up on the same page.

Comment: And the problem you're having is what?

Comment: it isnt working nothing pops up.. i get a unrecognized expression error.. the button comes up in the style I want but the .click function seems to not work

Comment: What is `.#emailWrapper` (the thing you're adding a click handler to) supposed to match? Did you mean `#emailWrapper`?

Comment: i deleted it and still error ... returns null

Comment: `url.dialog({ … ` Where is `url` defined? Also, "i get a unrecognized expression error". You should post the exact error (including the line number and what line that corresponds to in your code) in your question.

Comment: can you create [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: here is my new code:

$('#emailWrapper').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#emailWrapper').dialog({
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 140,
        modal: true,
    });

now the button goes away when i click it

Comment: That's most likely because you're doing `$("#emailWrapper").dialog({ … });` You're turning (or at least trying to turn) your button (the `emailWrapper` element) into a dialog. That strikes me as quite odd. Usually you use a hidden `div` or something like that.

Comment: I created the div shown above but now i get an error stating expected an identifier instead saw '<' also another error saying missing ; before statment and id not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here

```
$('.#emailWrapper').click(function () {
```

From the rest of your code, you appear to be referring to an element with an ID of emailWrapper. You want to remove the dot from your selector.  Inside your function, you refer to an event object.  You have to pass this in your function.

```
$('#emailWrapper').click(function (event) {
```

**EDIT**

You're second issue is that you're trying to make your button be the dialog.  You really need to create a div that will contain your dialog content. For example

```
<div id="mydiv">
   <p>Display some stuff here</p>
</div>
```

Then define it as

```
$('#mydiv').dialog({
  resizable: false,
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 140,
  modal: true,
});
```

Then open it inside your click event

```
$("#mydiv").dialog("open");
```

Comment: ok i fixed that part to this... now when i click on it the button goes away: 

 $('#emailWrapper').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#emailWrapper').dialog({
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 140,
        modal: true,

Comment: Can you take a look at the code i added at the top and let me know what im doing wrong..? Still a beginner

Comment: Did you change the id of the button that opens the dialog? Where are you defining the `<div>` (it needs to be in the body of the web page while the dialog definition needs to be inside a `<script>` tag

Comment: If someone can take a look at the last code and the comment below it id appreciate it!!

Comment: You're getting your dialog div and other element confused.  You defined loadEmailFriend as the dialog yet your code is trying to open a dialog using emailWrapper. `$("#emailWrapper").dialog("open");` should be `$('#loadEmailFriend').dialog("open");`